# Bad allocation problem

Tags: c++, vscode, terminal

No se porque cuando me dispongo a ejecutar el programa pasandole los ficheros de entrada y salida me salta el error de bad allocation.
Llevo varios días intentandolo y no lo consigo si alguien lo supiese me sería de gran ayuda.
Muchas gracias de adelanto.

```
PS C:\Users\josep\Downloads\Projecte> ./exh_proj_f.exe entrada.txt sortida.txt
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include<new>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;
const int INF = 100000;

// structure containing the data for each model available
struct model{
  int cars_num; // #cars for that model
  vector<bool> upgrades; // true in the position of the upgrade the model offers
};

// structure containing all external data needed
struct database{
  int C, U, K; // C: #cars, U: #upgrades, K: #models
  vector<pair<int,int>> windows; // intervals for each model
  vector<model> mdl; // model characteristic's
};

// reads all the info provided by the input files and and returns a database
// with the data organised
void read_info(int argc, char** argv, database& info){

  // if the number of files provided isn't enough or there are extra returns an error
  if(argc != 3){
    cout << "Syntax: " << argv[0] << "input_file outputfile" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  // opens input files and stores the data provided
  ifstream in(argv[1]);

  int c, u, k;
  in >> c >> u >> k;

  info.C = c;
  info.U = u;
  info.K = k;

  // reads the car's window each stages can take on
  vector<pair<int,int>> w(u);
  for(int i = 0; i < u; ++i){
    int ce;
    in >> ce;

    w[i].first = ce;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < u; ++i){
    int ne;
    in >> ne;

    w[i].second = ne;
  }

  info.windows = w;

  // creates the models body with the data provided
  for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i){
    int id, a;
    in >> id >> a;

    // vector with the improvements
    vector<bool> im(u);

    for(int j = 0; j < u; ++j){
      bool h;
      in >> h;
      im[j] = h;
    }

    // creates the model with the obtained info
    model n;
    n.cars_num = a;
    n.upgrades = im;

    // adds the model to the vector
    info.mdl.push_back(n);
  }

  // closes the input file and returns
  in.close();
  return;
}


// Provided a partial solution filled up to the position 'l-1', returns which
// will be the new penalization if placed a car of class 'ncl' in the position l
int calc_new_pen(const database& info, const vector<int>& part_sol, int ncl,
                 int l){
  int tot_pen = 0; // contains the new penalization found

  // iterates for each upgrade to find the penalization
  for(int i = 0; i < info.U; ++i){

    // finds the window the upgrade can take (ce cars from a window of ne cars)
    int ce = info.windows[i].first;
    int ne = info.windows[i].second;

    int c_h_u = 0; // contains the cars having the upgrade

    // if it reaches the last position
    if(l == info.C - 1){
      // iterates all final windows possible
      for(int j = l-ne+1; j < info.C; ++j){
        // for each window selects all cars having the upgrade
        for(int h = j; h < info.C - 1; ++h){
          if(info.mdl[part_sol[h]].upgrades[i] == true) c_h_u += 1;
        }

        // looks into the new car's class we are about to place
        if(info.mdl[ncl].upgrades[i] == true) c_h_u += 1;

        // if we have more classes having the upgrade than possible we add the proper penalization
        if(c_h_u > ce) tot_pen += c_h_u - ce;

        // counter with car's having the upgrades is reset
        c_h_u = 0;
      }
    }

    // if its within the initial positions
    else if(l < ne){
      // iterates from the first position to the current position minus one
      for(int j = 0; j < l; ++j){
        if(info.mdl[part_sol[j]].upgrades[i] == true) c_h_u += 1;
      }

      if(info.mdl[ncl].upgrades[i] == true) c_h_u += 1;

      if(c_h_u > ce) tot_pen += c_h_u - ce;
      }

    else {
      // iterates for the upgrade window's spam
      for(int j = l-ne+1; j < l; ++j){
        if(info.mdl[part_sol[j]].upgrades[i] == true) c_h_u += 1;
      }

      if(info.mdl[ncl].upgrades[i] == true) c_h_u += 1;

      // if the number of cars for that window beats the cars that can have it,
      // adds a penalization
      if(c_h_u > ce) tot_pen += c_h_u - ce;
    }
  }

  return tot_pen;
}


// Prints a solution to the cars order problem in an output, as well as the cost
// and the time it has taken the machine to calculate ir
void print_sol(const vector<int>& part_sol, const int& min_pen, char** argv,
               clock_t& t){
  // Gets the output file from the parameters provided
  ofstream out(argv[2]);

  int n = part_sol.size();

  // Sets precision to 1 decimal
  out.setf(ios::fixed);
  out.precision(1);

  // Finds the time the system has taken to calculate the answer
  double ct = (clock() - t)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  // Prints (overwriting the output file) the penalization, cost and car's order
  out << min_pen << ' ' << ct << endl;
  out << part_sol[0];
  for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i) out << ' ' << part_sol[i];
}


// Finds the optimal distribution of the cars by generating different answers
// and rewriting the answer in the output each time a better solution is found

// Index 'l' corresponds to the current postion of the partial solution
// 'part_sol' that is being generated and 'part_pen' stores the penalization
// accumulated up to that point by that partial answer
void generate(const database& info, vector<int>& part_sol, int& min_pen,
              int part_pen, int l, vector<int>& used, char** argv, clock_t& t){
  // BASE CASE: position index l reaches the end of the partial solution vector,
  // aka all cars are placed
  if(l == info.C){
    // minimum penalization is actualized and partial solution printed on the
    // output file
    min_pen = part_pen;
    print_sol(part_sol, min_pen, argv, t);
  }

  // RECURSIVE CASE
  else {
    // iterates for each car class
    for(int i = 0; i < info.K; ++i){
      // if there's still cars of that class to place
      if(used[i] < info.mdl[i].cars_num){

        // finds the new penalization if we place that car type
        int np = 0;
        if(l != 0) np = calc_new_pen(info, part_sol, i, l);

        // checks new penalization doesn't beat min penalization up to that point
        if(np + part_pen < min_pen){
          part_sol[l] = i;
          part_pen += np;
          used[i] += 1;
          generate(info, part_sol, min_pen, part_pen, l+1, used, argv, t);

          // disregards the changes for new combination
          part_pen -= np;
          used[i] -= 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  // reads and stores provided info
  database info;
  read_info(argc, argv, info);

  // initiates the clock
  clock_t t = clock();

  vector<int> part_sol(info.C); // vector with the partial solution
  int min_pen = INF; // minimum penalization found up to that point
  vector<int> used(info.K, 0); // vector with the number of cars placed for each class

  // finds the optimal solution by generating partial solutions and keeping the best
  generate(info, part_sol, min_pen, 0, 0, used, argv, t);

  
}
```

Os dejo por aquí el código utilizado. El problema es que este programa igual en otra terminal funciona; recibe el fichero de entrada y lo imprime por el de salida. Pero no se por que razón en la terminal de mi ordenador sale el bad alloc este y no encuentro solución en ningún lugar.

Comment: Bienvenido. El error significa que hay un problema con la memoria pero difícilmente te podamos ayudar si no dejas el código. Mira cómo crear un [example]

Comment: @Mateo ya te he colgado el código, haver si así lo pudieses ver me seria de gran ayuda. Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: Para que tu pregunta atraiga más atención, pon en el título el error _exacto_ que estás teniendo. Recuerda además que no todos pueden ver las imágenes, así que haz un _copypaste_ del error y pégalo en la pregunta. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿Podrías también agregar la entrada que recibe el archivo y explicar brevemente cuál es el propósito del programa?

Answer (score 0):

La excepción [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) se da cuando tu sistema no puede alojar memoria.

Veo que estás usando `std::vector`, el cuál internamente pide memoria para almacenar datos. Pides memoria en el [constructor de `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) o en su función miembro [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Si en el constructor pasas un valor muy grande puedes quedarte sin memoria y lanzar un `std::bad_alloc`; si llamas a `push_back` en un bucle muy largo también puedes quedarte sin memoria y lanzar un `std::bad_alloc`.

Prueba tu código con archivos más pequeños.